# How to access specific attributeds and output information in the object

Tags: python

Hello there I have a JSON dataset with a whole bunch of entries like that:
There are multiple entries for each date that look the same, just different dates with multiple entries of people added to that date.
So I could get information by using
`{json_content['12-1-2021'][0]['name']}`

```
    {'12-1-2021': [{'initials': 'IS',
    'name': 'Sam',
    'age': 23,
    'address': 'Freedom Dr',
    'city': 'Seattle',
    'state': 'WA'},
{'initials': 'SD',
'name': 'Sed',
'age': 21,
'address': 'Washington Dr',
'city': 'Phoenix',
'state': 'AZ'}]}
```

I want to iterate somehow through the dataset and select for instance all the people who live in Seattle without the date(maybe add the date later- not sure the requirement on that yet). But I can't do that without specifying the date since the beginning.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely can. Since you don't care about the keys of the dictionary just go through the values:

```py
names = [
  person['name']
  for date in json_content.values()
  for person in date if person['city'] == 'Seattle'
]
```

If you don't want to make any assumptions about how valid the structure of the json is, you can check it explicitly along the way in addition to checking the city:

```py
[
  person['name']
  for date in json_content.values() if isinstance(date, list)
  for person in date if all([
    isinstance(person, dict),
    'name' in person,
    'city' in person,
    person['city'] == 'Seattle'])
]
```

Both of these get you `['Sam']` for your sample json.

Comment: you are not filtering on the city of the person.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a complete person record and you are having future scope for a date then I will suggest the below code.

```
for person_records in json_content.values():
    if isinstance(person_records, list):
        for person in person_records:
            if person.get("city") == "Seattle":
                print(person)
```